# I made minor changes to already UV mapped model. Can I keep most of the original UV layout?

Tags: uv

I built, uv mapped and then painted a character model.  Then I decided I wanted to change the geometry and went back in to tweak it.  This included deleting a few faces and adding a some new ones.  I'd like to keep most of my existing UV layout while generating UVs for the new faces.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Give a try to the options (top right of 3d view in edit mode) "correct face attributes"... but no guarantee it will work in your case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. Have you tried to unwrap only the new faces and move it in the right place in the UV editor?

Comment: I'd been unwrapping the full model.  I'll try just unwrapping parts of it.